# funcion onclick que al dar click en el botón se de click en otro botón pero sin darle click en el otro boton,que lo haga automáticamente

Tags: php, javascript, funciones

El código JavaScript de la función del primer botón:

```js
  


<script>
  function downloadCanvas(canvasId, filename) {
    // Obteniendo la etiqueta la cual se desea convertir en imagen
    var domElement = document.getElementById(canvasId);
 
    // Utilizando la función html2canvas para hacer la conversión
    html2canvas(domElement, {
        onrendered: function(domElementCanvas) {
            // Obteniendo el contexto del canvas ya generado
            var context = domElementCanvas.getContext('2d');
 
            // Creando enlace para descargar la imagen generada
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = domElementCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            link.download = filename;
 
            // Chequeando para browsers más viejos
            if (document.createEvent) {
                var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                // Simulando clic para descargar
                event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0,
                    false, false, false, false,
                    0, null);
                link.dispatchEvent(event);
            } else {
                // Simulando clic para descargar
                link.click();
            }
        }
    });
}
 
// Haciendo la conversión y descarga de la imagen al presionar el botón
$('#boton-descarga').click(function() {
    downloadCanvas('top-img', 'certificado.png');
});
</script>
```

```html
<!-- el boton que quiero que haga los 2 clicks -->
  
  
  <button  class="btn btn-primary"  id="boton-descarga" onclick="ing();">Descargar certificado</button>
  
 
  
  
  <!-- el boton que quiero que se haga click al oprimir el otro: -->
  
  <button    type="submit" name="submit"  id="submit"  class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" hidden>Ingresar</button>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer una función con onclick que al dar click en el botón "1" ejecute la función de dar click al botón "2 sin" yo darle click a ese botón ?

Doy click a los 2 botones pero solo presionando el botón 1,
espero explicarme bien y me entiendan si pudieran poner un ejemplo seria de mucha ayuda.

Comment: pon el código de lo que lle as para poder darte ayuda

Comment: Hola seria de bastante ayuda el que compartas el código de como lo tienes actualmente, ya que de otra forma lo unico que te puedo decir es que dentro de tu función mandes a llamar la función del segundo evento.

Comment: un boton hace un submit y el otro ejecuta una funcion me gustaria que al dar click al primero este ejecute la funcion de tomar captura de pantalla(esta funcion funciona bien) y luego de hacer la captura de click al boton que guarda un formulario en mysql

Comment: Yo haria $("#BONTON1").click(function(){ $("#BONTON2").click(); //OTRAS FUNCIONES DEL PRIMER BOTON });

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo de como quedaria el script? y gracias

Answer (score 3):

Solo tienes que agregar esto al handler del primer boton: `$('#submit').click();`

```js
  function downloadCanvas(canvasId, filename) {
    // Obteniendo la etiqueta la cual se desea convertir en imagen
    var domElement = document.getElementById(canvasId); 
    
}

function ing() {
  console.log('submit');
}
 
// Haciendo la conversión y descarga de la imagen al presionar el botón
$('#boton-descarga').click(function() {
    downloadCanvas('top-img', 'certificado.png');
    $('#submit').click();
});
```

```html
el boton que quiero que haga los 2 clicks
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  
  <button  class="btn btn-primary"  id="boton-descarga" onclick="ing();">Descargar certificado</button>
  
 
  
  
  el boton que quiero que se haga click al oprimir el otro:
  
  <button    type="submit" name="submit"  id="submit"  class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" hidden>Ingresar</button>
```

Comment: agrego esto $('#submit').click(); arriba del function?

Comment: Dentro de `$('#boton-descarga').click(function() {`

Comment: si funciona pero.. no me descarga la captura de pantalla solo guarda el formulario

Comment: // Haciendo la conversión y descarga de la imagen al presionar el botón
$('#boton-descarga').click(function() {
 $('#submit').click();
    downloadCanvas('top-img', 'certificado.png');
});

</script>

Comment: Intenta ponerlo dentro de `onrendered: function(domElementCanvas) {` al final

Comment: excelente ya funciona muchas gracias!!